# How to get nested array in swagger definition

Tags: json, swagger, swagger-2.0

Trying to get this Json outpun with swagger definitions:

```
{
"attachments":[{
"attachment": 
  {
    "filename": "string",
    "filedata": "string",
    "filetype": "string"
  }
},
{
"attachment": 
  {
    "filename": "string",
    "filedata": "string",
    "filetype": "string"
  }
}]
}
```

My swagger.json looks like this:

```
"attachments": {
    "type":"array",
    "items": {
    "$ref": "#/definitions/attachment"
  }
},          

"attachment": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "filename": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "filedata": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "filetype": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    },
```

And I get this Json on the request:

```
"attachments": [
  {
    "filename": "string",
    "filedata": "string",
    "filetype": "string"
  }
],
```

How do I get the first Json syntax trough Swagger references?

Comment: You say "nested array" but your first example is an object/hashmap. Which one is correct?

Comment: Sorry, the goal is to get an array, I edited the question with the proper syntax. Thankyou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an extra definition for the wrapper object that has the `attachment` property:

```
"attachmentWrapper": {
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "attachment": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/attachment"
    }
  }
}
```

Then change your array definition to use this wrapper as the item type:

```
"attachments": {
  "type":"array",
  "items": {
    "$ref": "#/definitions/attachmentWrapper"
  }
}
```