# Swagger Validator complaining about seemingly well-formed request

Tags: rest, validation, express, swagger, swagger-2.0

I'm using the [`swagger-express-validator`](https://github.com/gargol/swagger-express-validator) to validate inputs to a small API server (using Swagger 2 format)

My `path` definition is as follows

```
/api/v1/users:
  post:
    produces:
      - "application/json"
    parameters:
      - in: body
        name: ids
        description: Array of user ids to be processed
        required: true
        schema:
          $ref: "#/definitions/ArrayOfIds"
    responses:
      200:
        description: success
```

`ArrayOfIds` is defined as follows

```
Id:
  type: string
ArrayOfIds:
  type: array
  items:
    $ref: "#/definitions/Id"
```

Sending a post request to the server as follows:

```
POST /api/v1/users HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json
Host: localhost:3000
Connection: close
User-Agent: Paw/3.1.7 (Macintosh; OS X/10.13.6) GCDHTTPRequest
Content-Length: 35

{
  "ids": ["abcd12345"]
}
```

Results in an error

```
Request Invalid: POST /api/v1/users
 [ { keyword: 'type',
    dataPath: '',
    schemaPath: '#/type',
    params: { type: 'array' },
    message: 'should be array' } ]
```

I am however able to access `req.body.ids` in my Express route controller code and it contains the correct value `['1234abc']`.

Do you have any idea as to why the validator is complaining about the request?  It looks fine to me.

Comment: Related (or duplicate): [How do I wrap JSON objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36545405/113116), [How to get nested array in swagger definition](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43876840/113116)

Comment: I'd say related rather than a dupe as those refer to reponse objects not request params.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your request body does not match the definition. According to the definition, the array in the request body must be unwrapped:

```
POST /api/v1/users HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
...

["abcd12345"]
```

If the array needs to be wrapped into the `ids` wrapper property, the request body should be defined as `type: object` with the property `ids` that contains the array:

```yaml
    parameters:
      - in: body
        name: ids
        description: Array of user ids to be processed
        required: true
        schema:
          type: object
          properties:
            ids:
              $ref: "#/definitions/ArrayOfIds"
```

Comment: Interesting.  So the `name` in the case of the `body` param is ignored / redundant. Thanks so I changed my code to just extract the array directly from the `body` rather than changing the `swagger` defn.